# In Selenium Java, clickAndHold() method without element is not working

Tags: java, selenium

I need to drag a line with the CTRL key onto secondElement but it doesn't have a locator in the DOM since it is in the Canvas element. But I can locate it according to firstElement position.

With the following script, I can see the selenium selecting the line but not dragging on the second element. I don't know what is wrong with this method.  Here is the code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(firstElement,-10,-15)
    .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).clickAndHold().perform();
actions.moveToElement(secondElement).release().keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

Comment: Might want to try that all in one line/actions chain... (don't call perform til the end)  If that doesn't help you may need to generate certain HTML5 events.  (dragstart, dragend, drop...)

Comment: I tried one line chain but it doesn't work too. I was thinking of js executor but since the line doesn't have a locator, I couldn't find a way to locate it according to the first element

Comment: canvas's can have webelements layered on top to retrieve events.  If that's not the case, you'd have to hack out the coords.

Comment: The panel is based on google maps so streets and roads can't be located. There is a route shown as a line which I mention in my question drawn by the application but it is in the canvas element. I have some polyline elements in the dom but I can't highlight them on the browser to make sure if it is related to that line. I tried with coordinates even though they are right, the action class is not doing its job.